# How install command-line tools for Xcode 15.2

Tags: xcode

I just installed Xcode 15.2 (under Sonoma 14.2.1). Does that include the corresponding command-line tools?

If not, how do I install them? (If I execute "xcode-select --install" I get response that the tools are already installed. I note that "xcode-select -p" give result
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer".)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Command Line Tools are contained within the Xcode bundle and then symlinked into the system. No need to install the standalone Command Line Tools.

The standalone Command Line Tools package contains the same binaries for use without Xcode (for instance, Homebrew needs the Command Line Tools installed for some actions).

Comment: I use MacPorts instead of Homebrew. Do I need the standalone Command Line Tools, or is the symlink to the ones with Xcode sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

When I install a new version of Xcode, there are always some additional things to install to work with non-Xcode actions, as @Gummibando mentions. The way I usually get the additional command line tools is to start Xcode, and then use the Xcode menu to select "Open Developer Tool" -> "More Development Tools". That opens the Apple website (Apple developer credential needed) which features downloads of Xcode-related stuff. As of today (2024-01-10), there is no download for Xcode 15.2 command line tools. The latest, from December, is Command Line Tools for Xcode 15.1.
The command line tools I installed with 15.1 appear to be working fine after I installed Xcode 15.2.
@Gummibando: When you say "the standalone Command Line Tools", where are they "standing alone"? Is that a separate download different from what I described?

Comment: There is ususally a separate "Command Line Tools for Xcode XX.X package". If you check the dev download website, the Command Line Tools package for Xcode 15.1 was released a few days after Xcode 15.1, so maybe it will just take a little bit longer for the standalone package to be released. Or maybe there was absolutely nothing changed in terms of the command line binaries and a 15.2 package would be redundant.